# XOR encryption program not encrypting the whole sentence

Tags: c++, encryption, key, xor

This is an updated question with the proper code and a couple of examples so that you guys can see what is going on. I'm having a really hard time trying to make work an encryption program. I can only use chars and no strings in any sense.

I'm trying to encrypt any message that the user inputs in the program using the XOR operator, as you can see in my code. The complete code is the following:

```
include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void encrypt_stand_message();
int y = 0;
int x = 0;
int option= 0;
char cipher = ' ';
char message[300];
char key[] ="ALCtALC sixth headed civic outlying mayflower irregular boneless prevail freebase delirious projector dreamless";


main ()
{

    cout<<"Plese choose option?"<<"\n\n";

    cout<<"1. Cipher text\n\n";

    cout<<"\n";
   
    cin>>option;

    switch(option){
    
        case 1:

        encrypt_stand_message();
    
        exit(1);
    
   }


   }



void encrypt_stand_message(){

    system("clear");

    cout <<"Please enter the code to encrypt?"<< "\n\n";

    cin.ignore();

    cin.get (message, 500);

    char a = message[x];

    char b = key[y];

    while(a!='\0'){
  
        cipher = a ^ b;
    
        cout << cipher;

        x+=1;
        y+=1;
    
        a = message[x];
    
        if(key[y]=='\0'){
        y=0;
        }
    
        b = key[y];

     }

    }
```

The results that im getting are in the following screenshots:

[image: Example 1]

[image]

As you guys can see, the program is not encrypting the whole text that the user is providing! I don't know what is going on, but I'm getting crazy trying to solve and make properly work this program. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: If *ever* there were a program built to single-step in a debugger, this is it.

Comment: "*this is an updated question*" - is this a continuation of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68465614/)? If so, why post this as a new question, instead of as an edit to the previous question?

Comment: On a side note: `cin.ignore();` should be after `cin>>option;`, not inside of `encrypt_stand_message()`.

Comment: This should have been an edit to your previous question, not an entirely new question. Please delete one of them, and review the site guidelines for the proper way to do this in the future. Also, consolte output is text, and can be copied and pasted as such directly into your post. The images were totally unnecessary; images should be used only when the issue can't be demonstrated without them.

Comment: Heads up: 300 is not the same as 500.

Comment: The reason im asking is because the debugger method didnt work! jaja come on! thanks for the advice to the guys that helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code *IS* "encrypting" the whole user input.  You are just not taking into account that some of the characters that your `^` xor operation is producing are *unprintable* control characters, like `0x06`, `0x1B`, even `0x00`, etc.

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/xRrhSR)

Also, you probably should not be XOR'ing the input against the `key`'s null terminator.  You can get rid of the `if` block inside of your `while` loop, and instead use the `%` modulus operator, eg:

```c
int keylen = strlen(key);
...
b = key[y % keylen];
```

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/7zSEdx)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer!